# Autofac DependencyResolutionException

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, aerospike

I am getting following error:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(System.String, Int32)' on type 'AerospikeClient'.

Following is the stacktrace of autofac:

> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.BoundConstructor.Instantiate()
> at
> Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
> context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__11_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DelegateMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext
> context, Action`1 next)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(ResolveRequestContext
> ctxt)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext
> context, Action`1 next)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(ResolveRequestContext
> ctxt)    at
> Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext
> ctxt)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext
> context, Action`1 next)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(ResolveRequestContext
> ctxt)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ScopeSelectionMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext
> context, Action`1 next)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(ResolveRequestContext
> ctxt)    at
> Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext
> ctxt)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
> currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest
> request)    at
> Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest
> request)    at
> Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest
> request)    at
> Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext
> context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
> Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext
> context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
> Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext
> context, Type serviceType)    at
> Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

Following is my registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<AerospikeClient>().As<IAerospikeClient>()
                .WithParameter("hostname", _configuration["AerospikeHostName"])
                .WithParameter("port", int.Parse(_configuration["AerospikePort"]))
                .SingleInstance();
```

`_configuration` is getting passed to my autofac module and it is of type `IConfigurationRoot`. I am doing this so that I can pass values from outside.

If I change the above registration to:

```
builder.RegisterType<AerospikeClient>().As<IAerospikeClient>()
                .WithParameter("hostname", "172.27.159.44")
                .WithParameter("port", 3000)
                .SingleInstance();
```

then it starts working. However I don't want to hardcode my values like that. Then I lose my chance of overriding them based on different environments.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the actual type returned from `_configuration["AerospikeHostName"]`? Is it actually `string`, or is it something that happens to be assignable to string?

Comment: @AlistairEvans your question forced me to closely inspect return value for `AerospikeHostName`. It turned out to have a " " (space) in front of it. Fixed that and now everything is running cool. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlistairEvans if you post your comment as answer, then I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: It's always the simple things. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the actual type returned from `_configuration["AerospikeHostName"]`. Is it actually `string`, or is it something that happens to be assignable to string?

Equally, check the actual value used is valid, because Autofac should be fine expecting that string value.

Also, in future, consider using the built-in [diagnostics](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/debugging.html#diagnostics) to get a clearer picture of what exceptions are being thrown during resolve operations.